# have mapped drives using wifi

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I have some mapped drives like a T:\ drive and it is mapped to e.g. \\server10\whatever.

When my computer is connected to the internet using a cable it always works, but when I am connected via a wifi usb device it never works. I also don't have wifi the first 10 seconds after I log in.

Is there a way to delay the network drive mapping until after the internet is up in this case?

Comment: How are you connecting to the resource?  Is the Server remote from you?  Is the wireless connection on the same subnet as the wired connection (or is the wireless connection a cellular connection)?

Comment: @John the wireless connects to the company network. And the cable also places me on the company network. The mapped drive is also in the company, and even though it doesn't get mapped then after the internet begins to work then I can see the server the drive is mapped to. The server is part of the company, but in a physical sense it is in another building.

Answer (score 1):

Wireless connections require the OS to start before the connection starts. Ethernet will start before fully logged on.

You need to delay the network mapping connection.

There is a policy to do this.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/gg486839(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

See this section:

> Depending on your environment, you may want to disable Fast Logon
> Optimization. You can do this with Group Policy, using the Always wait
> for the network at computer startup and logon policy setting. To
> access this setting:

Another way (I do this) is to wait for full startup and map the folders once started. This always works.